# Не получается распечатать поле класса

Tags: c++

Изучаю `С++`. У меня есть такой код:

```
struct Cls {
    Cls(char c, double d, int i) {
        this->c = c;
        this->d = d;
        this->i = i;
    }
public:
    char getC() {
        return c;
    }
private:
    char c;
    double d;
    int i;
};
int main() {
    Cls *cls = new Cls(1, 2.0, 3);
    std::cout << (*cls).getC() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

На консоль распечатывается пустая строка. Не понимаю почему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А кстати, как у вас выглядит символ с кодом 1?... У меня (Windows) честно выводит рожицу :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы хотели увидеть `1`, то нужно передавать символ, а не код 1:

```
new Cls('1', 2.0, 3);
```

А вообще я бы еще подчистил (это не принципиально) ваш код так:

```
struct Cls
{
    Cls(char c, double d, int i):c(c),d(d),i(i){}
    char getC() const { return c; }

private:

    char c;
    double d;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    Cls *cls = new Cls('1', 2.0, 3);
    std::cout << cls->getC() << std::endl;
}
```

Вкратце - в конструкторе не присваивать, а инициализировать. Если структура - лишний `public` ни к чему. Ну и функция-член, ничего ме меняющая - лучше делать ее константной.

Comment: Теперь не получается вывести вызов метода `char getD() const { return d; }`  на консоль :(

Comment: @ВасилийНикпуп, но ведь `d` у вас типа `double`, а не `char`: `char getD()` → `double getD()`.

Comment: @eanmos я самый невнимательный человек на планете)))